# Why does Pandoc not retrieve the image file?

Tags: knitr, rstudio, pandoc, r-markdown

On RStudio version 0.98.501 I had a long `.Rmd` file which was easily converted to html once I clicked **KnitHtml** button. The Knitting process, as I understand, created several folders including images (some manually added by myself), figures, cache and a `knitHtml` folder which included final `.html` file. I recently downloaded RStudio version 0.98.894 (preview release) because I wanted to use more features. Now, when I click **KnitHtml** I get following error:

```
pandoc.exe: Failed to retrieve C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/Trajectory1/images/vissim-view.png InvalidUrlException "C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/Trajectory1/images/vissim-view.png" "Invalid scheme" Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
```

I copied all the images including the `vissim-view.png` as indicated above, from the images folder to the `knitHtml` folder and clicked the button again. This time it gave the same error related to image file which R would create i.e a plot. How to resolve this?

Comment: Never use absolute paths unless you absolutely have to. Use relative paths whenever you can. Put your image under the same directory as the Rmd file, and use `![](vissim-view.png)`.

Comment: Pandoc on Windows is not great at handling paths. If you want, you can revert to 0.98.501's KnitToHTML behavior by adding the comment `<!-- rmarkdown v1 -->` to your document. See [Migrating from RMarkdown V1](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_migrating_from_v1.html).

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to use rmarkdown version 2 to add table of contents. It seems to me now, after Yihui's comment, that it is almost impossible to knit a Rmd file created on an older version of RStudio in a new version. I either have to change the paths of all images or be content without table of contents. By the way, thank you Yihui I will keep this in my mind to not use absolute paths next time.

Comment: @umairdurrani If a relative path works, please write it as the answer and mark it as accepted (you are welcome to answer your own question on SO).

Comment: @Yihui Changing to relative paths worked perfectly, it created table of contents and displayed all figures. However after some time I clicked knitHtml again to make sure `cache=TRUE`was working but got the following error with no output: `pandoc.exe: Could not find data file ./Trajectory1-new_files/figure-html/pdf_velocity.png
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 97`. Please note that I copied all the images to the same directory where Rmd file resides. I don't know if its me or a bug in preview release of RStudio.

Comment: It knits perfectly if I change `cache=FALSE`. But gives error as above with `cache=TRUE` in global chunk options.

Comment: @Jonathan does it mean that I can't use rmarkdown v2 on Windows? Hope this gets fixed soon as I am keen to use Shiny in rmarkdown for my work! I work for a major bank and having this can potentially lead to great PR for the R community. Tks!

Comment: I am also having the same issue, using `cache = TRUE` results in an error (`pandoc.exe: Could not find image './tuto_files/figure-latex/wcex2.pdf', skipping...`). I am trying to find a workaround (because I am generating a pdf with ca. 100 figures), without success at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered a similar error like this:
*pandoc.exe: Could not find data file ProjectPart1_files/figure-html/sample_Mean_versus_Theoretical_Mean-1.png
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 97*

And one sentence from this [page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_rcodechunks.html)
solved my problem.

"If you run into problems with cached output you can always clear the knitr cache by removing the folder named with a _cache suffix within your document’s directory."

When the error occurred, there exactly existed a folder with name like "ProjectPart1_cache" in the working directory. After I deleted it, the error was removed.

Answer (score 11):

While there are multiple correct solutions above, I'd like to add that a common cause of this error is syntactical, when the author accidentally wraps the file name in the markdown in quotes:

```
![my image]("my_image.png")
```

This will result in pandoc being unable to locate the file. I find this mistake to be easy to make in knitr, since we are intertwining R scripts with markdown.

The correct way to insert the image is:

```
![my image](my_image.png)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Yihui's comment above was the answer that worked for me, and it's not a current answer here, so I'm adding it:

> "Never use absolute paths unless you absolutely have to. Use relative paths whenever you can. Put your image under the same directory as the Rmd file, and use `![](vissim-view.png)`."

Using a relative path worked for me where an absolute path did not.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, Jonathan's answer in the comments worked for me. I added:

```
<!-- rmarkdown v1 -->
```

To my document, and it did the trick. He claims that this is because Pandoc on Windows is not great at handling paths.

If someone else would write a better answer, I will gladly erase this one.

Comment: I would recommend using latest version of R Studio and using relative paths. That's how I am doing it now.

Comment: Any updates on this?

I'm new with RStudio (and the related tooling) and I'm having the same error.